# Can I update an iTunes App with a new project but the same Bundle ID?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

If I update my old app that's currently in the App Store by creating a new Project that has the same Bundle ID, will my users lose the data they've stored in `NSUserDefaults`?

All the code will just be copy/pasted to new project; enabling ARC will be the primary change.

Comment: ARC has no relationship with the existing user data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, users will not lose data if you update your app using the same bundle ID. Yes, changing your app to ARC is allowed and will not affect the users data.

Comment: Great, Thank You.  I just had to hear it from some one else.